# Is there a name for the words used after dialogue?

Tags: terminology

For example,  "he said"  "she replied" "they inquired."

Comment: With direct speech, the _verb_ involved (if any) is perhaps best referred to as a _quote verb_ or _quotative verb_ (to distinguish it from those verbs, often the same words, used with _that_ or _whether / if_ in indirect speech - _reporting verbs_ proper). There are some surprising ones - _grin_, _smile_, no verb at all, the modern _go_ and _be like_.

Answer (score 8):

They are usually called **speech tags** by writers.

Answer (score 7):

In functional grammar, they're known as **projecting clauses**.

Answer (score 7):

Toolan (1998:106) refers to them as *matrix clause* or *framing clause*; he gives the examples of:

> *She said, 'I'm sorry I can't stop right now.'*

and

> *She wondered why those types always picked out her to ask.*

The second example is of course reported or indirect speech, but the same principle applies.

---

Toolan, M (1998) *Language in Literature: An Introduction to Stylistics*, Hodder Education

Answer (score 3):

*Speech tags* is commonly used by writers, as given already, and often abbreviated to just *tags*, though like many short terms it only makes sense if you know the fuller form.

Those other than the simpler *said* and *asked* are often called *Swifties* or *Tom Swifites* or *said-bookisms*.

The first two because the "Tom Swift" series of children's adventure books were written by someone who was so afraid of the repetition of *said* that he would go to great lengths to avoid it, and so came up with a great variety of other tags, which made the tag stand out more than the dialogue most of the time.

The last because you could once buy "said books" that provided near-synonyms of *said* and adverbs that could be applied to *said*, just so that you too could turn perfectly good dialogue into writing that jarred and buckled under the reader's eye like a snake having a epileptic fit.

*Swifty* is also applied to a game where you deliberately produce such pointless tags, but with a pun too (*"It's freezing," he muttered icily*).