# Is there a term for the aspect of style where an author indicates who is speaking?

Tags: terminology, writing-style, dialogue

In a novel, for example, imagine the following sentence:

> "I like chowder", **Helen said**.

What I'm looking for is the highlighted part.  There are many different ways that particular sentence can be modified, eg:

- Helen said, "I like chowder"
- "I like", Helen said, "chowder".
- "I like chowder" (the author doesn't tell us Helen said it, but we figure it out from surrounding context).
- Helen jumped from her seat.  "I like chowder!"  (here again it is implied that Helen was the speaker, but the author doesn't say it directly).
- Helen chimed in, saying that she liked chowder.

In my experience, the variations in the way the speaker is identified can have a huge influence on the overall quality of a novel.  Is there a term, either for this quality of style, or for the specific part of the sentence wherein the speaker is identified?

Edit:  I found a possible duplicate [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101571/term-for-the-identification-of-the-person-speaking-in-a-dialogue), but I'm not sure if it fully applies, as that appears to be reference specifically towards a screenplay or something else meant to be performed.  I more interested in the term as it is used in prose as a descriptive phrase.  Might be the same word. If so, feel free to flag as duplicate.

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Comment: There are terms for the different strings, whichever format they appear in. The quote is the quote. The identifying tag (where present) is known as the **speech tag** and includes a quote verb or quotative verb (often _say_, but modern ones include _smile_, _frown_). This part of the answer is certainly addressing a duplicate ([Is there a name for the words used after dialogue?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105043/is-there-a-name-for-the-words-used-after-dialogue/105045#105045)) Question (1), 'Is there a term for this quality of style?' may be better asked on Writing.SE.

Comment: NB Because report structures are different from quote structures, using the term 'reporting clause' for a speech tag (subject + quotative verb) is unhelpful and best avoided. And as some verbs ('say', 'ask' for instance) may be used in both report and quote structures, it is better to restrict the use of 'reporting verb' say for a _usage_ in a report structure.

Comment: [Louise Harnby](https://www.louiseharnbyproofreader.com/blog/dialogue-tags-and-how-to-use-them-in-fiction-writing) has written what seems an excellent article on how to handle speech tags (aka dialogue tags) for best effect in writing fiction: when to front them, when to intersperse them with dialogue, when to omit them ... but this is writing/style advice, not on-topic at ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - appears I may be off topic with part of my question  Thanks for the links.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - thanks for that as well.  Seems there’s a lot of names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was introduced to them as **speech tags** and **name tags**, in a high-school English class 14 years ago. Semantics have become much more concrete, and formalized, due to the advent of the internet, and sites like the one your reading this on.

The term that I would say is most correct would likely have to be "dialogue tags", but if you were to use any of the other two mentioned in the opening of this excerpt, other writers would know what it is your referring to.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That you very much.  After reading @EdwinAsworth’s comments above, I did some research, and this is indeed what I was after

Comment: Nice answer. Did not know that. PLEASE! do not let *"invent"* become a new word or usage in our groaning meta-vocabulary.

Comment: @Elliot Oh really, invent is frowned upon?

Comment: Please don't re-answer clear duplicates. It's against the spirit of the site, increasing bloat and making searches more tedious. 'Speech tags'  has already appeared as an answer on ELU, and the synonym 'dialogue tags' is mentioned above.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I don't think I am re-answering anything, as I only answered this question once.

Comment: Please don't echo / reproduce previous answers already given to questions that are clear duplicates.

Comment: @j D3V Glad he fixed the typo. Thank you Justin.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Responsibility for duplicates falls first, but not entirely, on the person asking the question. This question is not closed, so initially it doesn't appear to be a duplicate. It would require the execution of search queries to ascertain, _whether or not_, it is a duplicate, consequently, I would argue that it was not so apparent — _or "clear" as you put it_ — that it was a dup. To address a similar subject, I don't understand why this question hasn't been closed due to a flag if it is in-fact a dup. Did you flag it as a dup?

Comment: I have a question, maybe someone here knows the answer. On Stack Overflow we have clear documentation on what a good answer and question looks like. Is there anything like that for this Stack Exchange site?

Comment: (a) If a question has been flagged as a duplicate, it is hardly in the spirit of the site to add a subsequent answer without checking to see if the suggested duplicate is clearly so. (b) The original post had two separate questions, the first the duplicate, and the second also off-topic asking for comments about the differing nuances different forms of representation of direct speech conveyed. Style / writing advice belongs on Writing.SE (though I added in a comment what I consider a very useful link).